# Unable to override the Launcher Icon

Tags: android, image, android-launcher, android-icons

I want change the existing App Icon. I follow steps **App Folder->Create New->Image Asset->Asset Type(Image)**. When I upload a new icon, it's not allowing me to go Next screen. I can only see the warning 'Icon with the same image already exist' but no specific error. In my other project I can easily override the same icon. Please guide where I am missing?

Comment: Please also specify which IDE you are using.

Comment: I think this is happening because the images are the same. Anyway you can delete the previous image without the need of overriding.

Comment: Actually I already tried replacing square icon files in mipmap-xxxx directories and that is working fine but I don''t have proper round icons. I also tried some websites which are creating ready to use icons as per android directories but again no round icons found there too. Creating/Replacing launcher through Android Image Asset handles it properly. Please suggest if there is any other way to resolve it.